# create Dynamic class object

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#, and now I got stuck on dynamic objects (if there's such a thing).

I have two Buttons and two TextBoxes on a userform, so what I am trying to do is to instantiate an object each time I click `Button1` and assign its name property value to whatever text is in TextBox1. After a few instances I want to retrieve a name value of any created object (something like `MessageBox.Show(obj[int.Parse(TextBox2.text)].name)`).

The code throws error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```cs
TEST[] o;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    o = new TEST[10];
    o[1].name = textBox1.Text;
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(o[1].xcount.ToString());
}
```

I want read a property value for a specific object by object index/count.

Comment: Hi. You need to edit your question because it is not very clear what your question is. Perhaps, state what you want to achieve, then explain what you have tried and is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice of using arrays is one of the correct approaches.

First, you should move the initialisation of the array outside the method, so that you don't create a new array (and hence discarding the old objects) every time you press button 1:

```
TEST[] o = new TEST[10];
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Next, add a variable indicating where the next element should be added to the array:

```
int next = 0;
TEST[] o = new TEST[10];
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Inside `Button1_Click`, you need to create a `TEST` object with the `name` of `textBox1.Text`, assign it to `o[next]`, and increment `next` so that the next element can be inserted.

```
o[next] = new TEST { name = textBox1.Text };
next++;
```

Try working out how to implement `Button2_Click`.

Obviously, this program can only store a fixed number of `TEST` objects. If you want to store an unknown number of objects, you need a `List<TEST>`:

```
List<TEST> o = new List<TEST>();
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    o.Add(new TEST{ name = textBox1.Text });
}
```

Comment: o[next] = new TEST { name = textBox1.Text };
next++; Thanks this works

Answer (score 1):

Here you are instantiating array of  `Test` class every time. Create one class (Instead of dynamic) with property called Name, which will store value of `textbox1` at every button click.

Use that property to retrieve name when you click `Button2`

```
Test[] testArray = new Test[10];
int index = 0;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(index < 10)  //To avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBound error
   {
      testArray[index++] = new Test() { Name = textBox1.Text };
   }

}
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Read Name of first element in an array
    string firstName = testArray.FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
    MessageBox.Show(firstName);
}


public class Test
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it sounds easy, but if the first object is assigned the property name 'A' and the second object  is assigned the property name 'B'. how do i access  the property name('A') for first object?

Comment: @Joel *how do I access the property name('A') for first object* ? Do you mean to say how do I access property name where value is A?

Answer (score 0):

After you have created the array `TEST` it contains 10 positions all containing `null`. You must first create the `TEST` objects

```
o = new TEST[10];
// o[1] is null here.
o[1] = new TEST(); // Create object.
o[1].name = textBox1.Text;
```

Or

```
o = new TEST[10];
TEST test = new TEST();
test.name = textBox1.Text;
o[1] = test;
```

Or, with an object initializer

```
o = new TEST[10];
o[1] = new TEST{name = textBox1.Text};
```

But note that the array indexes are zero-based. I.e., the first element of the array is `o[0]` and the last one `o[9]`.

Also, note that your `Button1_Click` method creates a new array each time and thus discards any values store before.

Answer (score 0):

first, your Button1_Click does reset your o array each click. 
What you would want to do is to move it out there, probably in an initializing method, or in the constructor. A global declaration will also do.

second, System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' is thrown because you are trying to access an Array slot that is not yet defined.

```
    o = new TEST[10]; //new array here
    o[1].name = textBox1.Text; //and then you access slot[1] immediately
```

What you would want to do is to set slot[1] first.

```
   o[1] = new Test();
```

To avoid this error in the future, you would want to make sure that a slot is instantiated before accessing it.

```
   if (slot[i] != null)
   {   slot[i].name = "nam"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, your input helped me to write this awesome program as begginer:
int next = 0;
        TEST[] o = new TEST[10];
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            o[next] = new TEST { name = textBox1.Text };
            next++;
        }
        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(o[int.Parse(textBox2.Text)].name);
        }